# http://localhost is not loading

Tags: xampp

I have installed Xampp to use wordpress, but after installing Xampp with Apache, MySql running.....I go to the browser and type "http://localhost", nothing happens, just blank screen.

My apache server was not running, I came to know that IIS was the problem and had to disable it.

Could anyone solve this issue as the http://localhost is not working to make xampp and wordpress run.

Below is the Port-Check results >

```
RESULT
------

Service Port Status
==============================================================================
Apache (HTTP) 80 Program: C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
Apache (WebDAV) 81 free
Apache (HTTPS) 443 Program: C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe

MySQL 3306 Program: C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe

FileZilla (FTP) 21 free
FileZilla (Admin) 14147 free

Mercury (SMTP) 25 free
Mercury (POP3) 110 free
Mercury (IMAP) 143 free
Mercury (HTTP) 2224 free
Mercury (Finger) 79 free
Mercury (PH) 105 free
Mercury (PopPass) 106 free

Tomcat (AJP/1.3) 8009 free
Tomcat (HTTP) 8080 free

Press <Return> to continue.
```

Comment: seemingly silly question, but what browser are you running? some browsers handle localhost differently, and in particular, Chrome is not always able to hit it when there is not an active internet connection.

Comment: Would be a better fit for ServerFault, methinks?

Comment: Jonathan - "seemingly silly question" > If it is a silly question i wouldn't have posted it here, i would have just used my common sense to solve this problem.

I use Firefox browser, same problem in Opera, IE! Not using Chrome. 

Do you have any solution for the "silly question" again??

Comment: I think Johnathon was stating that his question about which browser seemed silly not your question...

Comment: Just a thought, but do you already have some content inside your htdocs folder? I don´t know if there is something in there (i.e. index.html) by default

Comment: Diskilla - well, to run something from the htdocs folder, i need configure the Xampp first. 

I followed till step 11 in this below website, but the 12th step which shows the xampp screen doesn't load >
http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/web-development-tutorials/using-xampp-for-local-wordpress-theme-development/#comment-75109

Answer (score 1):

```
Service              Port   Status
===================================
Apache (HTTP)          80   SYSTEM
Apache (WebDAV)        81   free
Apache (HTTPS)        443   SYSTEM
```

That's almost exactly what I'm looking at and mine is working.  I would check your firewall, when IIS was running could you get to it?  Also browse to http://127.0.0.1 if you can get to that link it may be a DNS/Hosts file issue.  can you get to https://localhost ?

Comment: I have disabled the IIS, as Apache in Xampp was stopped after few seconds of starting it! http://127.0.0.1 and https://localhost are blank again.

Comment: Yeah, what I'm saying is before you disable IIS did http://localhost work?  I'm trying to identify if it's an issue with XAMPP or your computer.

Comment: Nope, localhost didn't work before IIS was disabled, i had same problem then what am facing now, blank screen!

Answer (score 1):

Enable the [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) PHP configuration option so that you can see the error(s) that the PHP engine is trying to show you.

Comment: How do i do that??

Comment: Edit `php.ini` in a text editor.

Comment: okay! but what should i change here to enable >

; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to load the page from another PC?  Try http:\computername or http:\ipaddress.

Also is Wordpress configured to be in the root directory.  I think by default it is something like, http:\localhost\blog

Comment: Nope, i don't have another PC. For wordpress to work, i need to configure Xampp first, that itself is not loading, any solution?